# error CS8803: Top-level statements must precede namespace and type declarations

Tags: c#

I don't know how to write `c#` code. I am trying to run a sample code here - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/nosql/quickstart-dotnet?tabs=azure-portal%2Cwindows%2Cpasswordless%2Csign-in-azure-cli#create-account

This is the code I have copied in `powershell`. When I do `dotnet run`, I get error

```
/home/manu/Program.cs(24,1): error CS8803: Top-level statements must precede namespace and type declarations. [/home/manu/manu.csproj]

The build failed. Fix the build errors and run again.
```

Code

```
// See https://aka.ms/new-console-template for more information
using Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos;
using Azure.Identity;

// New instance of CosmosClient class
using CosmosClient client = new(
    accountEndpoint: Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("COSMOS_ENDPOINT"),
    tokenCredential: new DefaultAzureCredential()
);


// C# record representing an item in the container
public record Product(
    string id,
    string categoryId,
    string categoryName,
    string name,
    int quantity,
    bool sale
);


// Database reference with creation if it does not already exist
Database database = client.GetDatabase(id: "cosmicworks");

Console.WriteLine("Hello, World!");

Console.WriteLine($"New database:\t{database.Id}");


// Container reference with creation if it does not alredy exist
Container container = database.GetContainer(id: "products");

Console.WriteLine($"New container:\t{container.Id}");


// Create new object and upsert (create or replace) to container
Product newItem = new(
    id: "70b63682-b93a-4c77-aad2-65501347265f",
    categoryId: "61dba35b-4f02-45c5-b648-c6badc0cbd79",
    categoryName: "gear-surf-surfboards",
    name: "Yamba Surfboard",
    quantity: 12,
    sale: false
);

Product createdItem = await container.CreateItemAsync<Product>(
    item: newItem
);

Console.WriteLine($"Created item:\t{createdItem.id}\t[{createdItem.categoryName}]");

// Point read item from container using the id and partitionKey
Product readItem = await container.ReadItemAsync<Product>(
    id: "70b63682-b93a-4c77-aad2-65501347265f",
    partitionKey: new PartitionKey("61dba35b-4f02-45c5-b648-c6badc0cbd79")
);

// Create query using a SQL string and parameters
var query = new QueryDefinition(
    query: "SELECT * FROM products p WHERE p.categoryId = @categoryId"
)
    .WithParameter("@categoryId", "61dba35b-4f02-45c5-b648-c6badc0cbd79");

using FeedIterator<Product> feed = container.GetItemQueryIterator<Product>(
    queryDefinition: query
);

while (feed.HasMoreResults)
{
    FeedResponse<Product> response = await feed.ReadNextAsync();
    foreach (Product item in response)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Found item:\t{item.name}");
    }
}
```

What is the right way to structure the code?

Comment: What is your .NET version

Comment: Which .NET project is you created/used? The file scope namespace only supports in .NET 6 and with C# 10. For your reference: https://carole.dev/blog/new-in-c-10-file-scoped-namespaces/

Comment: Just because you're running it from PowerShell doesn't make this a PowerShell question. (I'd also suggest it doesn't really have anything to do with Azure - you could remove everything Azure-specific from the question and you'd have the same problem.)

Comment: firstly, I appreciate you answering the question. Community consists of people of different skills and knowledge. If you don't like question, just don't answer it or be tolerant.

Comment: I *did* answer it - I'm just saying that it would have been better if you'd tried to work out whether this was *actually* related to PowerShell and Azure. (And now that you've been advised that it isn't, you still haven't edited the question to remove the irrelevant tags...)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your current code structure is:

- `using` directives
- A top-level statement (declaring the `client` variable)
- A record type declaration
- More top-level statements

As the error message says, all top-level statements must come *before* any type declarations.

Two options to fix this:

- Stop using top-level statements: create a `Program` class with a `Main` method and put your code in that, and declare the `Product` record separately
- Just move the `Product` record to below all your top-level statements, or into a different file